# Trouble with Terminal Mac (ENCODING) - Not displaying character from Java >127

Tags: java, macos, encoding, terminal

Actually I'm having some trouble with the display encoding in my terminal window on mac.

I'm running a simple program in Java:

[image: MySimpleProgram]

And after the compiling when i run that code I face with this result:
[image: ResultOfExecution]

The number of the variable `z` do not match the exact unicode value!

All my preferences are set to UTF-8, in the editor and also in my terminal, but I can't find a way to solve this problem!

UPDATE:

Also here the writing and the compiling of the program:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using the following Java program:

```
/* A.java */
class A
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    for (char c = 'A'; c < 270; c++)
    {
      System.out.print(c);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

then I get the following output:

```
 $ java -Dfile.encoding=ASCII A
 Default Charset: US-ASCII
 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
 $ java -Dfile.encoding=iso-8859-1 A
 Default Charset: ISO-8859-1
 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������??????????????
 $ java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 A
 Default Charset: UTF-8
 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿĀāĂăĄąĆćĈĉĊċČč
 $ java A
 Default Charset: UTF-8
 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿĀāĂăĄąĆćĈĉĊċČč
```

From the above you can see that ISO-8859-1 prints both '�' and '?'. The '�' means that it was not valid UTF-8, and the terminal could not print it, and the '?' means that Java could not convert the required character into that character set. This is why ASCII only has '?', as it can only convert ASCII characters.

The default file.encoding is taken from from your locale, which is why you may need to set your LC_CTYPE. Otherwise, your terminal needs to be set to understand UTF-8.

```
$ echo $LC_CTYPE
UTF-8
```

Comment: My terminal preferences are set to UTF-8 encoding. What about LC_TYPE?

Comment: Which terminal are you using? iTerm or Apples terminal.app? My test was done with iTerm, although it also works under terminal (just tested). You have 'Settings/Settings/Character Encoding'="Unicode (UTF-8)" and 'Settings/Settings/Set Locale environment variables on startup' checked? What version of OSX are you using?

Comment: I've all the things listed. I use the default terminal.app and the settings are ok, but there is no way to print the unicode characters. My version of OSX is 10.8.5

Comment: I am afraid that I can't help you then, this "just works" for me. As you can see from my test program and output. Have you tried this program? What does it print for you? I have updated it above, and put more information into the answer. If this doesn't help you, then I am afraid I don't know how to further assist.